# Android Create Image Gallery from App Folder

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gridview

I am working on an app and one of my activities is a screen that grabs all the images in a folder I made in the /data/ application folder. I would like to to grab all the photos lay them out in a grid format and then when a person clicks on one it blows it up to full size. Of course this gallery needs to change when new images are added to the folder.

Seems like it would be some thing simple to do but I am having some trouble implementing this I keep finding a lot of different solutions non of which seem quite right.

I'm assuming it would be some sort of gridview/listadapter combination.

What would the best solution to this problem?

EDIT

I have looked into these solutions 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html#example

but my confusion is code like this

```
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
};
```

What do I do about this since the amount of images will be constantly changing in my app folder. And how do I load the images out of that folder in the first place haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the the [Caching Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) in Android Developers site? I think it does something similar to what you want. It also provides the code of the example.

You should better store you images in a path inside the sd card, since they need to change dynamically. Then to get the image paths from that path, use something like this (asssuming that you only have images in that directory):

```
File imagesDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "yourpath");
for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) {
   if (f.isFile())
      String image_path = f.getPath();
      // make something with the name
}
```

Also, to load a bitmap from a file in your sd, use something like this:

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("your_image_path");
```

Just keep in mind to load a downscaled version of the bitmap for memory efficiency. See [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) for more information.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I figured out how to load the bitmaps in the ImageAdapter and I think this Caching Bitmaps will be a huge help in having the images available between activities. I may potentially have hundreds of bitmaps to load in the gridview is it safe to cache that amount of data?

Comment: @Dan Glad i could help:) I believe that caching is the best approach, in your case, since when you give your cache a certain amount of size, you can be sure your bitmaps won't exceed this size potentially causing `OutOfMemoryErrors` (provided the implementation is correct of course).

Comment: Ok, I'll play around with it a bit. Also whats the benefit of using ExternalStorage instead of how I currently have it in the /data/app/myapp my fear was that the user may not have an SD card.

Comment: @Dan From what i understand, you are using the internal storage in your app. You can keep it that way. I personally prefer to save large quantities of data in the external memory but it is a matter of preference. Check out this link (if you haven't already) for an overall idea of the storage options you have in Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: So I didn't end up caching the bitmaps but I did use that for loop you had to populate an array of filenames. I then used those filenames to get the images and set the bitmaps in imageviews later. But that for loop was what I needed to create an array for the ImageAdapter to use. Thanks!